# Mensagem de alerta em asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Eu tenho em uma aplicação em Asp.Net MVC um formulário que termina da seguinte forma

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
</div>
```

Eu preciso que assim que o usuário clicar no botão 'Salvar' surja um pop up ou alerta com uma informação pra ele e com o botão 'ciente' e 'cancelar'. As informações então do formulário só serão enviado ao banco após a confirmação do ciente no pop up e não quando o usuário clicar no salvar inicial. 
Qual a forma mais simples de fazer isso?

Comment: Nessa sua função ai FechaModal() ja tentou colocar um pop up e dentro dele a lógica ? Ou então coloca outra função de gravação no pop up chamando essa FechaModal()... Talvez funcione.

Answer (score 3):

O jQuery UI possui a ótima `Dialog` que faz isso pra você:

> http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Ciente": {
          click: function() {
            // Coloque aqui sua lógica
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        },
        "Cancelar": { 
          class: 'cancel',
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz usando o `confirm()`

**HTML**:

```
<form action="teste.asp">
    <button id="save" type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

**JS**:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        var a = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja salvar as alterações?");
        if (!a){
        return false;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Link jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/x24bJ/

Answer (score 0):

Eu ja fiz algo parecido com isso, na verdade eu mesclei com javascript.

```cs
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Deseja deletar?');" 
    OnClick="Button1_Click">Delete</asp:Button>
```